# apt-get update error

Tags: apt, upgrade, error-handling

```
root@kali:~# apt-get update
Get:1 https://mirror.karneval.cz/pub/linux/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Reading package lists... Done        
E: Release file for https://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 11h 5min 54s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Please improve your question. Use the correct markdown syntax so that it becomes easier to read, add the actual question, tell us what you tried, provide more info, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify that your system clock is set correctly. If everything is fine on your end please report to the Kali Linux team (e.g. by opening a ticket at their [bug tracker](https://bugs.kali.org)).